# Is it possible to get all LESS errors no just the first one?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, less, web-essentials

I'm using LESS in Visual Studio 2015/Web Essentials and it's wonderful, but when there are multiple errors (such as when I rename a mixin), it only shows me the first error, and not the rest of them.

Is it possible to configure things so that I can see a list of ALL LESS compilation errors (or some reasonable number of them, like the first 100), so that I can assess the full consequences of such a rename?

Comment: No, there's no such option (a reasonable syntax recovering after a first error would require too much of normally unused code).

Comment: Why is that? The situation doesn't seem obviously more complex that C#, which shows all errors.

Comment: Less compiler is about 100kB - C# compiler is a few (tens if not hundreds) megabytes...